# Integrating medical dictionary to help enter text to asp:Textbox

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

My  requirement is to integrate medical dictionary in asp.net web application. I have a screen which is to be used by the doctors to enter text which is medical report of each patient. There is pretty more data to filled which are least preferred by the doctors. They need to get the medical dictionary integrated so that they can get the terms as they start typing into the textboxes. I googled which didnt help me. Can anyone help me how to approach this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I would start studying a Javascript framework with autocomplete support.

Try this:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/